# Check if the input file names with the file names in the config table

Tags: filter, azure-data-factory, lookup

I have a folder which contains many files and I got a configuration table in sql database which contains the list of file names which I need to load to Azure Blob Storage.

I tried getting the file names from the source folder using 'Get Metadata' activity and then used Filter activity to filter the file name but this way I have to hard code the filename inside the filter.

Can someone please let me know a way to do this?

Comment: its a bit confusing, where is this folder?, what do you mean by load ? do you want to copy from one container to other in Azure blob storage using config table as reference for list of files. Please share some screenshots of your current setup and what you have configured till now

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have the source files in a shared folder. The list of filenames to be loaded to the blob storage location is in a sql table I need to only copy the files those names are listed in the sqltable to Azure blob storage.

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

### here is an example:

I have below files in a folder.

[image]

And the below in **sql Config table**

[image]

This is how the sample pipeline looks like.

[image]

**1.** **Lookup** list of files from sql config table and using `foreach actvity` **append to an array variable**. In my example it is in `config_files`.

[image]

[image]

**2.** Using **GetMetadata**, list the **childItems** in the folder, and **append** the file names into another variable. In my example it is `files`

[image]

[image]

**3.** Use SetVariable activity to store the result i.e. the files that match from the entries in config table.

Expression: `@intersection(variables('files'),variables('config_files'))`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help KarthikBhyresh-MT . I followed your approach but getting an error. Sorry I am new to ADF. in the second for-each loop and the error messege is Error details
Error code
InvalidTemplate
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details
The function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Object'.

Comment: I am ble to resolve the error but the append variable is not returning any output. Thanks

Comment: okay you got error when appending the `file names` from `Childitems` array right ?

Comment: So the `ForEachActivity` setting should have this as its Items Property value `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRDbv.png  and inside foreach is as my 7th screenshot in answer

Comment: If its still empty, it means there are no files in the container or folder i guess

Comment: Thanks @KarthikBhyresh-MT. Its all good now.